# Why does Ubuntu log me out when I turn back my screen on?

Tags: suspend

I am trying to understand why is my Ubuntu being logged out when I close my monitor and turn it back on. I went in privacy settings and turned off the screen lock, it still happens. I turned off automatic suspend and blank screen off in the power settings. I even use caffeine to prevent anything from logging me out. When I turn off my TV and turn it back on, it still happens. However, when I change my input using the remote and switch it back to Ubuntu, I stay logged in.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a freshly built PC. It is an i5-8400 coffee lake, 4gb RAM, asrock 370m MB, only running an integrated gpu since it's for videos only (htpc) and want to consume less power as possible.

Here is the log, maybe something causes a crash (as read somewhere else on ubuntu forums).

```
Mar 24 10:02:52 joe-htpc kernel: [   11.767299] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mar 24 10:21:14 joe-htpc kernel: [ 1113.027561] perf: interrupt took too long (2552 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78250
Mar 24 10:25:53 joe-htpc kernel: [ 1392.126443] perf: interrupt took too long (3192 > 3190), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62500
Mar 24 10:33:52 joe-htpc kernel: [ 1870.411661] perf: interrupt took too long (4029 > 3990), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49500
Mar 24 10:38:55 joe-htpc kernel: [ 2173.602436] perf: interrupt took too long (5065 > 5036), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39250
Mar 24 10:46:31 joe-htpc kernel: [ 2630.112344] perf: interrupt took too long (6344 > 6331), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 31500
Mar 24 10:59:12 joe-htpc kernel: [ 3391.098739] perf: interrupt took too long (7940 > 7930), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
Mar 24 11:09:45 joe-htpc kernel: [ 4023.790507] perf: interrupt took too long (9994 > 9925), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 20000
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.490847] [drm:drm_scdc_set_high_tmds_clock_ratio [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Failed to read tmds config, err=-6
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.490932] [drm:intel_hdmi_handle_sink_scrambling [i915]] *ERROR* Set TMDS ratio failed
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.654313] show_signal_msg: 22 callbacks suppressed
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.654320] gnome-shell[1132]: segfault at 400000006 ip 0000000400000006 sp 00007ffdb6d27808 error 14
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.802982] [drm:drm_scdc_set_high_tmds_clock_ratio [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Failed to read tmds config, err=-6
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.803023] [drm:intel_hdmi_handle_sink_scrambling [i915]] *ERROR* Set TMDS ratio failed
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.811422] rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.864965] [drm:drm_scdc_set_high_tmds_clock_ratio [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Failed to read tmds config, err=-6
Mar 24 14:02:49 joe-htpc kernel: [14407.865001] [drm:intel_hdmi_handle_sink_scrambling [i915]] *ERROR* Set TMDS ratio failed
Mar 24 14:03:02 joe-htpc kernel: [14420.978276] rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 24 14:05:00 joe-htpc kernel: [14539.141142] [drm:drm_scdc_set_high_tmds_clock_ratio [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Failed to read tmds config, err=-6
Mar 24 14:05:00 joe-htpc kernel: [14539.141227] [drm:intel_hdmi_handle_sink_scrambling [i915]] *ERROR* Set TMDS ratio failed
Mar 24 14:05:01 joe-htpc kernel: [14539.308356] gnome-shell[2994]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f90ebe9f2d4 sp 00007ffc7dd17978 error 4 in libmutter-1.so.0.0.0[7f90ebe00000+142000]
Mar 24 14:05:01 joe-htpc kernel: [14539.804744] rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar 24 14:05:13 joe-htpc kernel: [14551.557178] rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 24 14:06:11 joe-htpc kernel: [14609.583412] [drm:drm_scdc_set_high_tmds_clock_ratio [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Failed to read tmds config, err=-6
Mar 24 14:06:11 joe-htpc kernel: [14609.583505] [drm:intel_hdmi_handle_sink_scrambling [i915]] *ERROR* Set TMDS ratio failed
Mar 24 14:06:11 joe-htpc kernel: [14609.669634] gnome-shell[4295]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f03a4c082d4 sp 00007ffe2eccdae8 error 4 in libmutter-1.so.0.0.0[7f03a4b69000+142000]
Mar 24 14:06:11 joe-htpc kernel: [14609.780453] rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar 24 14:06:24 joe-htpc kernel: [14623.069762] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

I left my htpc at around 11 and came back around 2pm. I reproduced the same problem again around 14:05 .

I see a couple of errors there but I still need help figuring out what is the main problem.

I think something happens when I turn back the screen on because when I leave it on for video encoding, the job gets done in the end... It only stops working when I turn back the screen on.
I searched all over the web and asked different people and no one is able to find a solution.

Help would be really appreciated as i am desperate in figuring out this problem! Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the exact same problems. The askubuntu community is very shy of answering questions like this, because issues such as this one have been long standing.

Comment: I found a partial solution. I just installed the lubuntu desktop environment and fixed that problem. I just don't use the default environment anymore. Lubuntu is also cleaner.